# Filter list data by dates in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have one list that contains birthdate of user. I want to display list of users whose birthday is one from now.

i want to display list of users whose birthdays are in one week from today.

My list is like

```
`<nb-list-item *ngFor="let yuvak of yuvaklist | slice:startDate:endDate ">
      {{yuvak.dateofbirth}}
      {{yuvak.firstname}} + + {{yuvak.lastname}}
  </nb-list-item>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @incNick Code, But that should we wrapped inside Pipe. You can create Angular pipe filter like this.

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'birthdayFilter',
    pure: false
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(item => this.isBirthdayInaWeek(item.birthday));
    }

    isBirthdayInaWeek(birthday){
        let weekSec = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        let today = new Date();
        let birthday = new Date(birthday);
        birthday.setFullYear(today.getFullYear());
        if (birthday.getTime() < today.getTime() && birthday.getTime() + weekSec > today.getTime()) {
            return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<nb-list-item *ngFor="let yuvak of yuvaklist | birthdayFilter ">
      {{yuvak.dateofbirth}}
      {{yuvak.firstname}} + + {{yuvak.lastname}}
  </nb-list-item>
```

Comment: You need to convert to valid format, like this. var from = 'dd/mm/yyyy'.split("/")
var f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0])

Comment: I converted into valid format. however, it still return false.

  isBirthdayInaWeek(dateofbirth) {
    let weekSec = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    let today = new Date();
    let dateParts = dateofbirth.split("/");
    let newbirthday = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]);
    newbirthday.setFullYear(today.getFullYear());
    if (
      newbirthday.getTime() <= today.getTime() ||
      newbirthday.getTime() + weekSec >= today.getTime()
    ) {
      console.log(true);
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log(false);
      return false;

    }
  }

Comment: here i put OR(||) condition instead of AND(&&). it shows me all the data. I guess something is wrong with getTime() method. Maybe it is not suited in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example below:

```
let weekSec = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
let today = new Date();
let birthday = new Date('1995-11-22');
birthday.setFullYear(today.getFullYear());
if (birthday.getTime() < today.getTime() && birthday.getTime() + weekSec > today.getTime()) {
  console.log('Happy birthday');
} else {
  console.log('...');
}
```